# Operation on mongodb array elements

Tags: mysql, arrays, mongodb, social-networking

I am new to mongodb. I am developing a social network website, for which I have entries in my collection "`users`". I have the following entry of particular user.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56a9fd3a5b4e12369150d6f0"),
"name" : "Amit",
"venue" : {
    "state" : "Madhya Pradesh",
    "city" : "Gwalior",
    "ll" : [
        "26.2215",
        "78.1780"
    ]
},
"lsv" : [
    0.05,
    0.17,
    0.05,
    0.14,
    0.18,
    0.24,
    0.17
],
"username" : "amit",
"frnds" : [
    {
        "id" : "udit",
        "type" : 1
    },
    {
        "id" : "nakul",
        "type" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

For each user I have to do operation on "`lsv`" array by matching some values of "`lsv`" of another user.

I am not able to get how to write the query for that.

Comment: Which type of operations do you want to do?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay i want to check for each value in "lsv" array with another user's lsv array ..operations like greater then or difference or cosine similarity ...

Comment: So you want to compare `lsv` values for two specified users, or do you want to find users matching current user's `lsv` values? And is it all values (sum of the values per example), or each one by one?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay yes something like that only